# Corrupted LVM Recovery

Tags: lvm, data-recovery

I had (paying attention to the past time here) a Centos 6.7 host who was migrated using Vmware conversion tool from a HyperV cluster. Therefore, the final configuration of its disks was:

```
/ dev / sda1 -> BOOT
/ dev / sdb1 -> Physical Volume
VG on / dev / sdb1
6 LVs on VG, root included
```

Time came and a logical volume was filled and VG did not have any free PEs to extend. So I made a ninja move and I extended `/dev/sdb` and went (wrongly) to rewrite the partition table to grow the PV. After that, the VM did not boot again because the LVM metadata was overwritten.

I tried several scenarios, the most successful was `strings / dev / sdb | head -n 1000` where I found copies of the LVM information (from the auto backups it makes to each modification), created a file from what seemed to be the latest configuration, created a PV with uuid same as the original and `--restorefile` the specified file. I continued with `vgcfgrestore` and `vgchange -ay` and all logical volumes became visible, but mount fails and I get the `bad superblock or wrong fs type` error. I have the feeling that the boundaries of LVs are not correct and I have overlaps with the old structure, hence the problem with the filesystem during mount.

Has any of you seen anything like that? Can anybody suggest any solution?

Comment: Possible help: https://superuser.com/questions/411697/lvm-volume-with-corrupt-mbr-how-to-mount-and-recover-data-from-it/411710

Comment: What was wrong about writing the partition table? What file system type are the volumes ?

Comment: Filesystem was ext4 on all logical volumes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have backups of the host configuration and data, it will be faster to reinstall the OS and restore.

Make a backup image of the LVs, such as with `dd` to a regular file, or perhaps a LVM snapshot.  Run a file system repair tool on the backup, such as  `xfs_repair -f /backup/lv`. This helps indicate if there is a recoverable file system.

Edit: you indicated ext4. Try all the superblocks as described over on UNIX Stack Exchange: [Recovering ext4 superblocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/recovering-ext4-superblocks).  The linked [data recovery page from the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) has some file extraction utilities if you really need files that don't have a backup.

---

Personally, I prefer to create PVs on entire disks without a partition table, such as `/dev/sdb`. Resized disks can be added immediately.

Comment: Filesystem was ext4 and I run a "fsck.ext4 /dev/vg_name/lv_name" but it still responds with "Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open..."

Comment: I don't think it is likely you will recover the file system intact. Try examining the superblocks using examples like one I linked in my edit. Then extract any valuable files from the image.